# How can I config my JerseyConfig with docker

Tags: java, spring, docker, jersey

I tried to make a REST API with spring and launching it with docker. But my jerseyConfig seems a bit broken.

I can run my spring API on my computer but it doesn't seem to work on docker and I don't know why :( . I found people that had the same problem as me on internet but it didn't really help me.

Here's my JerseyConfig:

```
package imt.projetrentree.projet.config;

import imt.projetrentree.projet.controllers.AuthController;
import jakarta.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {

        String basePackage = AuthController.class.getPackage().getName();

        packages(basePackage);
    }
}
```

When I try to run my project on Docker I have this error, but I don't know why:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'jerseyConfig' defined in URL
> [jar:file:/usr/src/app/target/projet-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/imt/projetrentree/projet/config/JerseyConfig.class]:
> Failed to instantiate
> [imt.projetrentree.projet.config.JerseyConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0]:
> Constructor threw exception

Note that if I change my `basePackage` variable to `JerseyConfig.class.getPackage().getName()` my project runs but I only have 404 errors.

I put a image of my docker directories.

Comment: Seem trying to build uber jar with Jersey doesn't work in Spring Boot. The `packages()` function breaks. But when you register the classes individually, it works. I've seen workarounds people have used, but I'm not sure what they are.